# When casting a small integer type to a wider one, is it safe to rely on &ing with a mask to remove the sign?

Tags: java, casting, binary

I have code that stores values in the range 0..255 in a Java `byte` to save space in large data collections (10^9 records spread over a couple hundred arrays).

Without additional measures on recovery, the larger values are interpreted as being negative (because the Java integer types use [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement) representation).

I got [this helpful hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771663/java-why-doesnt-binary-or-work-as-expected-see-code-below/771746#771746) from [starblue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49246/starblue) in response to a related question, and I'm wondering if this technique is safe to rely on:

```
int iOriginal = 128, iRestore;
byte bStore = (byte) iOriginal; // reading this value directly would yield -128
iRestore = 0xff & bStore;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's safe, indeed it's the most effective way of converting a byte into an (effectively) unsigned integer.

The `byte` half of the `and` operation will be sign-extended to an `int`, i.e. whatever was in bit 7 will be expanded into bits 8-31.

Masking off the bottom eight bits (i.e. `& 0xff`) then gives you an `int` that has zero in every bit from 8 - 31, and must therefore be in the range 0 ... 255.

See a related answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755715/is-this-statement-correct-in-java/755890#755890).